# Getting multiple errors when trying to use Prepared statements in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use prepared statements as a best practice but I keep getting these errors.

1) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'

2) Undefined index: finalExamGrade in C:\wamp64 (this goes for all the superglobal variables)

3) Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\wamp64\

Any fixes? Ideas?

PHP/MySQL

```
 require_once("DBCONNECT.php");
    $id = $_REQUEST['studentID'];
    $last = $_REQUEST['lastName'];
    $first = $_REQUEST['firstName'];
    $grade1 = $_REQUEST['test1Grade'];
    $grade2 = $_REQUEST['test2Grade'];
    $grade3 = $_REQUEST['test3Grade'];
    $grade4 = $_REQUEST['test4Grade'];
    $final = $_REQUEST['finalExamGrade'];


    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM students) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("issiiiii", $id, $last, $first, $grade1, $grade2, $grade3, $grade4, $final);

    $stmt->execute();

    var_dump($id, $last, $first, $grade1, $grade2, $grade3, $grade4, $final);

    $stmt->close();
    $connect->close();
```

Comment: You have an extra bracket `students)`. Remove the extra bracket and try.

Comment: Good catch but that did not work, I get the same errors still.

Comment: Oh, I read too quickly, you need to do an `INSERT` not a `SELECT`. Like this: `INSERT INTO tbl_name (columnname1,columnname2,columnname3) VALUES(1,2,3);`

Comment: So If I just want to run a SELECT statement then I don’t need to use prepared statements? I should only use prepared statements SQL INSERT?

Comment: You should use a prepare statement when you're doing a query with unknown values to prevent injection. Here are some good details: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: So in this particular instance do I need to use them?

Comment: Yes, you're taking in unknown values from the request. Please, refer to the documentation on php.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM students) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?)");
```

The above code is the root of all of your problem.

1. You use SELECT to insert data. It should be INSERT.
2. There is an extra bracket after `students` table.
3. The total parameters doesn't match with the `bind_param` one. There are 7 `?`
   in your code when you want to store 8 variables.

Change into this code

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO students(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("issiiiii", $id, $last, $first, $grade1, $grade2, $grade3, $grade4, $final);
```

I don't explain this code any further because it has been discussed on comments.